# NSURLSessionConfiguration always return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I'm trying to access an instance of `NSURLSessionConfiguration` 

 I've tried following statements to retrieve instance of `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.

Statement 1.

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *aConfig = 
     [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
```

Above statement returns `nil`

Statement 2.

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *aConfig = 
     = [[NSURLSessionConfiguration alloc] init];
```

Above statement also returns `nil`.

Can anybody tell me whats wrong with `NSURLSessionConfiguration` class?

[image]

Comment: where are you checking it's value ? breakpoint or NSLog ?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore - Give a try in NSLog & Breakpoint both. I've tried & it always return `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are using this for `iOS < 7.0`. If you can see it in docs you will find this `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0)` which means that it's available in `iOS 7.0`.

So I'll suggest you to use simulator or device running `iOS 7`

Comment: i am facing the same issue;thanks for the help ,as stuck from the last one hour.